# How to use Weibull curve fitting with loc parameter

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, regression, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit my histogram values to a Weibull_min model, so I get the function from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) and [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.weibull_min.html) and try to fit it with optimize.curvefit, it works ok with the wikipedia function; but if I add the loc parameter it doesn't fit and throws an error about: `OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated category=OptimizeWarning`

```
weibull = lambda x,c,scale,A: A*float(c)*((x)/float(scale))**(float(c)-1)*np.exp(-((x)/float(scale))**float(c))
    
paramopt,paramcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(weibull,bins[nonzero_incorrectvals],probs)
    
optres = my_weibull(bins,* paramopt)
    
plt.plot(bins,optres,"g-")
    
    
weibull = lambda x,c,loc,scale,A: A*float(c)*((x-float(loc))/float(scale))**(float(c)-1)*np.exp(-((x-float(loc))/float(scale))**float(c))
    
paramopt,paramcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(my_weibull,bins[nonzero_incorrectvals],probs)
#(here I get the error : OptimizeWarning: Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated category=OptimizeWarning)
    
optres = my_weibull(bins,* paramopt)
    
plt.plot(bins,optres,"y-")
```

Here is the resulting fit:
[image]

I don't understand why adding loc variable causes trouble.

Comment: Well, it is not an error but a warning. Better starting guesses might help, especially when looking at the final result. To improve your fit you can also implement the correct Jacobian instead of using the estimator.